# Clear a Linux storage device with sgdisk

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, mbr, gpt

I wish to use [sgdisk](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sgdisk) to delete all partition definitions and data from a storage device, then create a [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) and two partitions on it . The best solution I've found is to use the `-Z` and the `-o` options.

```
sgdisk -Zo \
    -n 1::16M -t 1:EF00 -c 1:ZNX_BOOT \
    -N 2 -t 2:8300 -c 2:ZNX_DATA /dev/[device]
```

This, however, fails if the drive was created with an MBR partition table or if a disk image was written to it. How can I get this command to wipe any disk regardless of the partition table style used on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is changing the question but is it possible for you to use [`wipefs`](https://github.com/mmalecki/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/wipefs.c) (which comes as part of the `util-linux` package)? `wipefs` understands how to clear all sorts of partition(ing) metadata and will correctly get rid of MBRs, GPTs (along with the backup GPT), filesystem signatures etc...

The examples from the [EXAMPLES section at the bottom of the `wipefs` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/wipefs.8.html#examples) illustrate how you might do this:

> **`wipefs /dev/sda*`**
>
> Prints information about sda and all partitions on sda.
>
> **`wipefs --all --backup /dev/sdb`**
>
> Erases all signatures from the device `/dev/sdb` and creates a signature backup file `~/wipefs-sdb-<offset>.bak` for each signature.

**WARNING**: As the name suggests `wipefs` **destroys data**! Please be careful...

Comment: What about it's performance? @K7AAY suggested `dd`, but it's too slow. If it's as fast (or at least similar) as `sgdisk`, then I could consider using it.

Comment: @luis-lavaire I'm amazed that a `dd` over one sector (assuming 512 byte sectors) of a disk is slow - it's pretty much the smallest write operation a disk could do! I'd guess that something else is wrong if that really was slow (e.g. `count=1` had been left off). I suppose you could use `bs=4k oflag=direct count=1` and see if that helps... Nonetheless to answer your question: in my experience `wipefs` finishes in less than a second (but the `dd` of the answer should have done so too).

Comment: No, I meant that wiping the whole disk with `dd` is slow.

Comment: @luis-lavaire that is true but that is not what the `dd` being suggested does. `bs=512` means each record is only 512 bytes and the `count=1` means only one record will be done before the `dd` finishes so it essentially clears only the first 512 byte of your disk so that `dd` will not be slow. A full `dd` of a disk is indeed very slow (and if you are ever going to do that with `dd` I strongly recommend making the `bs` 1M or higher). At any rate `wipefs` is way faster than a full `dd` of the disk :-)

Comment: Well, I have also tried clearing the GPT/MBR headers using `dd` (using `bs=512 count=1`). But I need to clear ALL the data on the device, not only the headers.

Comment: Technically you only need to remove the partitions and filesystem signatures to prevent accidental rediscovery (and remember GPT makes a back up of itself at the end of the disk so a `dd` of only the start of the disk is never enough when you're using it - you'd have to `dd` a bit of the end too). If you really mean "I need ALL the data anywhere on the disk destroyed" then yes you will have to use `dd` (or some other "overwrite" everything command) and using `sgdisk` will be nowhere near enough. Bonus: you're using `sgdisk` in zap and create mode so with that you're only changing metadata...

Comment: Not exactly. I'm using the `--zap-all` option, which should clear all the data on the device (including) the headers.

Comment: You're still only deleting metadata: `-Z, --zap-all Zap (destroy) the GPT and MBR data structures and then exit`. If you were to `dd` over the start **AND** end of the disk or you were to use `wipefs` you would achieve the same effect.

Comment: Well, the manual actually recommends the use of `-Z` instead of `-o` (`-o` means clear out all the partition data) and then partition the device normally. What I can't figure out is why it fails with some devices. For instance, if you create a bootable live USB and then run `sgdisk -Z DEVICE`, the device will still keep the label of the ISO image.

Comment: `sgdisk`'s `-Z` will also destroy MBR partitioning and/or any corrupt data in addition to GPT partitions: "Zap (destroy) the GPT **and MBR data**". As for your USB disk... it depends on where you are finding that label. Perhaps that label is part of the filesystem you are creating/copying to the disk?

Comment: After I run `sgdisk -Z` on a device; if I check it with `blkid`, I'm still able to see the ISO filesystem label (which is part of the ISO image that was written to the device).

Comment: Hmm `blkid` is probably grovelling around because UDF filesystems often aren't inside partitions. https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/e4386c8cc0f7f2cfb09781d963b353310a3cd93a/libblkid/src/superblocks/udf.c#L177 shows the routine. Did I mention that `wipefs` is good at removing filesystem signatures too? :-) It even uses `blkid` (https://github.com/mmalecki/util-linux/blob/5fdd35070ceb79589d52fa247d1b359bd2bdc471/misc-utils/wipefs.c#L33 )...

Comment: So, how would I use `wipefs` to achieve what I want?

Comment: Check out the EXAMPLES section at the bottom of the man page - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/wipefs.8.html#examples - that shows examples of dry runs and actually making `wipefs` perform real actions.

Comment: Can you please [add another answer | edit your answer] so I can accept it? `wipefs` worked just as spected. ;)

Comment: Is the answer any better now? Oh and thanks for persevering :-)

Answer (score 2):

I reget I see no way to do that exclusively within sgdisk, but fortunately, the kind folks at Virtualhelp.me have [suggested the use of dd](https://www.virtualhelp.me/linux/465-clearing-master-boot-record-linux) first, i.e.,

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

which is intended to overwrite that pesky MBR carrier partition which throws both sgdisk and [gdisk](https://linux.die.net/man/8/gdisk) for a loop.

Comment: Yeah, I kew about `dd`. The drawback is that it is VERY slow. That's why I prefer gdisk.

Comment: Understood, but since a review of man sqdisk and man gdisk showed they could not deal with MBR carrier partitions, thought I would offer what I could. EFI is soooo much better than MBR, I cringe every time someone says they don;t need EFI...

Comment: I guess that possibly using `while ! sgdisk -v /dev/device; do sgdisk -Z; done` could do the task. And I agree with you, that GPT is way better than MBR.

Comment: Note that if you must use `dd` to blank GPT partitioning then you will need to remove the first 20 Kbytes from the start **AND** the end of the disk. See https://serverfault.com/a/787210/203726 for details (also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table ).

Answer (score 0):

These commands did the job:

```
wipefs -af $DEVICE

sgdisk -Z \
    -n 1::132M -t 1:EF00 -c 1:ZNX_BOOT \
    -N 2 -t 2:8300 -c 2:ZNX_DATA $DEVICE
```

The first command clears the partition metadata, and the second one clears the data.